# JavaScript Infinite Loop help? Why is it happening?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

Edit: Here's a pastebin of the FULL code:
http://pastebin.com/EVAyxh2N

I've pasted my code below. If anyone can figure out why I'm getting an infinite loop from this, I'd love to see! Essentially, I have a for-loop inside of a foor-loop, and that worked fine, but I wanted to store rect data in an array so I could access it later, so I created another for-loop that deals with entries from the array, then creates rectangles for each of them.

```
// Create custom "tile" object
function tileObj(x, y, img) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = img;
}

// Create empty array to store tile data
var tiles = [];

// Create tile-grid, map.grid sized rectangles that will adopt tileset images
function gridTiles() {
    for (var x = 0; x <= map.width; x += map.grid) {
        for (var y = 0; y <= map.height; y += map.grid) {

            var newTile = new tileObj(x, y, "red");
            tiles.push(newTile);

            for (var z = 0; z < tiles.length; z++) {
                tile = tiles[z];
                ctx.rect(tile.x, tile.y, map.grid, map.grid);
                ctx.fillStyle = tile.img;
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
    }
}
gridTiles();
```

Comment: How did you determine it's an infinite loop?

Comment: Were do you define `map.width`?

Comment: I defined map.width and map.height above. I think it's an infinite loop, because my browser is behaving as if it is.

Comment: Which of three loops run forever?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming the one with the z variable, as it seemed to work just fine until I added it.

Comment: what is ctx? Is ctx.fillStyle causing an xhr? How expensive is ctx.fill()? FOr that matter, how is map defined?

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the FULL code: http://pastebin.com/EVAyxh2N

Comment: @NickDugger You should include all relevant info in the question. If your problem is caused by something not written here or needs such info to be discovered, your question is not well written. The link may break in the future and this question would lack important information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an infinite loop if map.grid is `<= 0`.

I think you want the `z` for loop after you have created all the tile objects:

```
// Create custom "tile" object
function tileObj(x, y, img) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = img;
}

// Create empty array to store tile data
var tiles = [];

// Create tile-grid, map.grid sized rectangles that will adopt tileset images
function gridTiles() {
    for (var x = 0; x <= map.width; x += map.grid) {
        for (var y = 0; y <= map.height; y += map.grid) {

            var newTile = new tileObj(x, y, "red");
            tiles.push(newTile);

        }
    }
    for (var z = 0; z < tiles.length; z++) {
        tile = tiles[z];
        ctx.rect(tile.x, tile.y, map.grid, map.grid);
        ctx.fillStyle = tile.img;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
gridTiles();
```

FYI, I don't think this was an infinite loop unless `map.grid` was `<= 0`.  It seems likely that it was a very, very slowly executing loop because you were cycling through every tile a ton of times.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this! You're right! It's even not that fast once fixed. It was definitely probably just really, really slow.

Answer (score 1):

How does gridTiles access the map object? Is it in the window or document scope?

Either way, make sure the grid value is positive, or you'll enter an infinitely loop.

```
function gridTiles(){
  var grid = map.grid; //assume you have access to it
  if (grid<=0){
    console.warn('Invalid grid width');
    return;
  }

  // continue your function

}
```

Comment: You are pushing new elements into the y-loop, and you're retrieving the length of the tiles array in the z-loop. Do you mean to get into a racing condition here? If not, store the original tile length and use that for the exit condition for the z-loop.